# How can I be close to being banned?

Tags: support, ban

I've received the message:

> "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more. Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I've got 2 questions (+5 and +1) and 1 answer (+2). How can I be close to ban?! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature/hurdle that was recently enabled site-wide across Stack Exchange (not just Code Review). See this meta.se post here:

- [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/241497);
- [What should I do when I see a “question ban warning”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234042/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-ban-warning)

The concept also takes in to account your deleted questions that had low scores. You can see your own deleted questions in your profile.

Comment: I've got no deleted questions nor answers. Can the ban be in need for fine-tuning?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You have two deleted questions, one at -4 and the other at 0, both of which were closed (moderators can see all of them).

Comment: Why can't I see them? Or rather - where can I see them? I've checked the profile but to no avail.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: There are certain reasons why users cannot see their own deleted posts (it should be on Meta SE somewhere).  All you can do is work with a moderator on them if needed.

Comment: @KonradViltersten We only show recently deleted questions (within last 60 days). Showing all deleted post vs that was a matter of some debate internally, but we ultimately landed on "it's better to show recent stuff than let folks obsess over something old of theirs getting removed because site policies evolved" (give or take). Both of your questions meet that 60-day criteria, so you can see the links to them here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/47625.